# Can i have multiple ons-popover in one single html?

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui

im currently working on phonegap, try to create popover using onsen UI. I have a problem to show diffent pop up screen. Not sure what was the issues here.

js code

> ```
>         ons.createPopover('pickup.html').then(function(popover) {$scope.popover = popover;}); 
>         $scope.pk = function(e) {$scope.popover.show(e);};
> ```

```
        ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {$scope.popover = popover;}); 
        $scope.show = function(e) {$scope.popover.show(e);};
```

html code

```
ons-button modifier="pickup_icon" id="p1" ng-click="pk('#p1')">Pick UP </ons-button>

<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item-container" id="u2" ng-click="show('#u2')">
```

script code

```
<!-- Module 1  -->
<script type="text/ons-template" id="pickup.html">
    <ons-popover direction="down" cancelable>
        <div style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.5;">
            <p>Option</p>
            <ons-button modifier="popup_btn" onclick="">Void</ons-button>
            <ons-button modifier="popup_btn" onclick="">Continue</ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-popover>        
</script>
<!-- Module 2  -->
<script type="text/ons-template" id="popover.html">
  <ons-popover direction="right" cancelable>
    <div style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.5;">
      <p>Customize</p>
            <ons-button modifier="popup_btn" onclick="">+</ons-button>
            <input type="text" class="text-input qty_style" placeholder="1" value="">
            <ons-button modifier="popup_btn" onclick="">-</ons-button>

    </div>
  </ons-popover>
</script>
```

is anyone having this experience doing phonegap on multiple popover? Thanks

Comment: the popover is working, but it always call to the Module 2 pop up for both button i had clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many popovers as you want, yes.

You create all of them in the beginning and store them inside `$scope`. Your problem is that you are storing them in the same variable, i.e. overwriting the first popover with the second one. Just name them `popover1` and `popover2` or whatever you want, like this:

```
ons.createPopover('pickup.html').then(function(popover) {$scope.popover1 = popover;}); 
$scope.pk = function(e) {$scope.popover1.show(e);};

ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {$scope.popover2 = popover;}); 
$scope.show = function(e) {$scope.popover2.show(e);};
```

Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/jPgdop

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Frans Dios, appreciated for your guide.